Python Match-Case: Invalid syntax error when comparing to a list
I'm using Dictionaries, i like to keep the keys in a list, for me, it makes it less of a hassle to maintain the code.
So in the code, I'm comparing some input string to the list of keys.
If I'm using If/Else statements, it works as expected.
But, if I'm using Match/Case, I'm getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".
I also tried casting each element to str().
I'm using PyCharm with Python 3.12
This works as expected:
test_types = ["Full range", "LF", "HF"]
test_selected = "Full range"

if test_selected == test_types[1]:
    print("mana")
elif test_selected == test_types[2]:
    print("banana")
else:
    print("error")

This does not:
test_types = ["Full range", "LF", "HF"]
test_selected = "Full range"

match str(test_selected):
    case str(test_types[1]):
        print("mana")
    case f"{test_types[2]}":
        print("banana")
    case _:
        print("error")


I refer you to PEP 634 to help you with the syntax

It's match test_selected: case a if a == test_types[1]: ... case b if b == test_types[2]: .... I'll find a dupe.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to match inequalities in Python ≥ 3.10?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Really, though, there's no reason to replace the if-elif statement with a match statement. You aren't doing any kind of interesting pattern matching.

In the match pattern, you cannot use evaluations such as str(x[1]), because match expects patterns. Below is the correct way to use match.
test_types = ["Full range", "LF", "HF"]
test_selected = "Full range"

lf, hf = test_types[1], test_types[2]

match test_selected:
    case lf:
        print("mana")
    case hf:
        print("banana")
    case _:
        print("error")


Please note that AI-generated content is banned on Stack Overflow.

Have you tested this to see if it works the way you think it does?
